# How to translate push tokens between NSData and NSString representations in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have used the following Objective C routines for years, to convert a NSData push token into a NSString (for use by a web side push service), and the inverse, to take a known NSString version of the token and recreate the NSData representation. Now, I find the need for the exact same capabilities, but in Swift.

The dataToHex Objective C code essentially uses printf formatting:

```
- (NSString *)dataToHex:(NSData *)data
{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:100];
    const unsigned char *p = [data bytes];
    NSUInteger len = [data length];
    for(int i=0; i<len; ++i) {
      [str appendFormat:@"%02.2X", p[i]];
    }
    return str; 
}
```

The inverse translation is:

```
- (NSData *)hexToData:(NSString *)str 
{
    const char *ptr = [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSUInteger len = [str length]/2;
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:len];
    while(len--) {
        char num[5] = (char[]){ '0', 'x', 0, 0, 0 };
        num[2] = *ptr++;
        num[3] = *ptr++;
        uint8_t n = (uint8_t)strtol(num, NULL, 0);

        [data appendBytes:&n length:1];
    }
    return data;
}
```

By "cleverly" overwriting a two byes in an ASCII array, the "0xXX" string is converted into a byte, which is then appended to the mutable data object.

Now that I'm coding in Swift, I need the same capabilities but have not found any posts with anything like the code above in Swift.

Answer (score 5):

Converting from the NSData representation as supplied by iOS matches the Objective C code almost line for line:

```
func dataToHex(data: NSData) -> String
{
    var str: String = String()
    let p = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)
    let len = data.length

    for var i=0; i<len; ++i {
        str += String(format: "%02.2X", p[i])
    }
    return str
}
```

However, given an NSString object, the conversion back to a NSData object is a bit harder. You might need to do this if you are testing in the Simulator, have a string token from a real device, and need it to say register with a service.

The first approach I took tried to replicate code I used before, by creating a string with character pairs, and calling `strtol`:

```
func hexToData0(str: NSString) -> NSData {
    let len = str.length/2
    var data = NSMutableData(capacity:len)!
    var num: [Int8] = [ 0, 0, 0 ]
    let ptr = str.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    for var i=0; i<len; ++i {
        num[0] = ptr[i*2+0]
        num[1] = ptr[i*2+1]
        var n = UInt8 ( strtol(&num, nil, 16) )

        data.appendBytes(&n, length:1)
    }
    return data;
}
```

I just felt the `strtol` was a bit of a hack, so I did the same using `NSScanner` that about the same code size, while most likely less efficient:

```
func hexToData1(str: NSString) -> NSData {
    var data = NSMutableData(capacity: str.length/2)!
    for var i = 0; i<str.length; i+=2 {
        let r = NSRange(location: i, length: 2)
        let s = str.substringWithRange(r)
        let sc = NSScanner(string: s)

        var val: UInt32 = 0
        let ret = sc.scanHexInt(&val)
        if ret {
            var b = UInt8(val)
            data.appendBytes(&b, length: 1)
        } else {
            assert(false, "Yikes!")
        }
    }
    return data
}
```

Then, it occurred to me that I could do it all in Swift, no Darwin or Foundation needed, at the expense of a few more lines of code:

```
// Swift 4
func hexToData(str: String) -> Data {
    let len = str.count/2
    var data = Data(capacity:len)
    let ptr = str.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

    for i in 0..<len {
        var num: UInt8 = 0
        var multi: UInt8 = 16;
        for j in 0..<2 {
            let c: UInt8 = UInt8(ptr[i*2+j])
            var offset: UInt8 = 0

            switch c {
            case 48...57:   // '0'-'9'
                offset = 48
            case 65...70:   // 'A'-'F'
                offset = 65 - 10         // 10 since 'A' is 10, not 0
            case 97...102:  // 'a'-'f'
                offset = 97 - 10         // 10 since 'a' is 10, not 0
            default:
                assert(false)
            }

            num += (c - offset)*multi
            multi = 1
        }
        data.append(num)
    }
    return data;
}
```

I'm using the final `hexToData` in my code.

Comment: Minor remark: You don't need the "0x" prefix in `hexToData0()` if you call `strtol(&num, nil, 16)`.

Comment: @MartinR updated code to reflect your comment - agree its a better solution than the older code using "0x"